# Not passing the same event_id from Pinterest Tag and API within a timeframe

Tags: pinterest, pinterest-api

I am sending page views, add to cart and purchase events through the Pinterest TAG and the API (through GA4 tag).

On the Event deduplication page on the Pinterest Platform, it says that page views and add to cart events have a unique tag overlap of over 90%, which if good, but the purchase (checkout) event has only around 30% overlap, which is an issue.

[image: Tag Deduplication]

The info that I got from Pinterest is that "the issue is not passing the same event_id via TAG and API within a timeframe."

Here is how the event_id is set up in the GTM:

Pinterest Conversion tag:
[image: Pinterest Conversion Tag]

GA4 tag:
[image: GA4 tag / Pinterest API]

In the server-side GTM the event data is inherited from the client.

I am using the same Event ID variable, so in my understanding, the same event_id should be passed over through the tag and the API.

I am also not sure what this timeframe is that they mention or how I could change it.

Any ideas?

I have made sure to use the same trigger for the Pinterest Conversion Tag and the GA4 tag (Pinterst API).

I tried to overwrite the event_id in the server-side GTM, the overlap rate dropped even further.